# How to view the contents of a nested table column in SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit

and SQL Developer version Version 21.4.1.349

Build 349.1822

I have a schema level type as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CHAR_TAB_20_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (20);
```

The above type is the datatype of the column order_consignee_tab in the table table_1.

When I execute the below select statement i get the output in SQL Developer

as follows which is not displaying the values in the nested table.

```
SELECT selection_id,
       order_consignee_tab
  FROM table_1
 WHERE col_1 = '206' AND selection_id = 'TEST';
```

Output:

> SELECTION_ID   ORDER_CONSIGNEE_TAB
> TEST           WMSPRD.CHAR_TAB_20_TYPE()

Can somebody please tell me how to view the values of the nested table column order_consignee_tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked about SQL Developer, then follow steps on this screenshot:

1. double-click the result of the `select` statement
2. click the pencil icon
3. view the result

[image]

Comment: Your column display is different than the OP because of Preferences, Database, Advanced, 'Display Struct Value in Grid' - ENABLE that.

Comment: Just did, @thatjeffsmith, thank you. Didn't change the output, still looks the same ("SCOTT.CHAR_TAB_20_TYPE('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')")

Comment: Then not sure why the OP is seeing differently, or maybe they aren't and :shrug:

Comment: I wouldn't know, @thatjeffsmith; maybe the OP will respond and provide some more info.

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith, I changed the settings as you mentioned and i am able to see the results in another nested table column. For my case the collection is empty...Thanks Littlefoot, i tried as you suggested...Clicked the pencil and the results now shows after changing the settings.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` to a table collection expression and then get the value from the `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudo-column:

```sql
SELECT selection_id,
       o.COLUMN_VALUE AS order_consignee
FROM   table_1 t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(t.order_consignee_tab) o
WHERE  col_1 = '206'
AND    selection_id = 'TEST';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  selection_id VARCHAR2(4),
  col_1        VARCHAR2(3),
  order_consignee_tab CHAR_TAB_20_TYPE
) NESTED TABLE order_consignee_tab STORE AS table_1__order_consignee_tab;

INSERT INTO table_1 (selection_id, col_1, order_consignee_tab)
VALUES ('TEST', '206', CHAR_TAB_20_TYPE('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'));
```

Outputs:

> | SELECTION_ID | ORDER_CONSIGNEE |
> | --- | --- |
> | TEST | ABC |
> | TEST | DEF |
> | TEST | GHI |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f09dd99918a5c5b3428aa835bc87999f)*